# Looping through pages of Web Page's Request URL with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, request

I'm looking to adapt this tutorial, (https://medium.com/better-programming/a-gentle-introduction-to-using-scrapy-to-crawl-airbnb-listings-58c6cf9f9808) to scraping this site of tiny home listings: https://tinyhouselistings.com/.

The tutorial uses the request URL, to get a very complete and clean JSON file, but does so for the first page only. It seems that looping through the 121 pages of my tinyhouselistings request url should be pretty straight-forward but I have not been able to get anything to work. The tutorial does not loop through the pages of the request url, but rather uses scrapy splash, run within a Docker container to get all the listings. I am willing to try that, but I just feel like it should be possible to loop through this request url.

This outputs only the first page only of the tinyhouselistings request url for my project:

```
import scrapy

class TinyhouselistingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tinyhouselistings'
    allowed_domains = ['tinyhouselistings.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.tinyhouselistings.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://thl-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/api/v1/listings/search?area_min=0&measurement_unit=feet&page=1'

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        _file = "tiny_listings.json"
        with open(_file, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
```

I've tried this:

```
class TinyhouselistingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tinyhouselistings'
    allowed_domains = ['tinyhouselistings.com']
    start_urls = ['']

def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://thl-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/api/v1/listings/search?area_min=0&measurement_unit=feet&page='
        for page in range(1, 121):
                self.start_urls.append(url + str(page))
                yield scrapy.Request(url=start_urls, callback=self.parse)
```

But I'm not sure how to then pass start_urls to parse so as to write the response to the json being written at the end of the script.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `allowed_domains = ['tinyhouselistings.com']` because the url `thl-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net` will be filtered out by Scrapy

Since you are using `start_requests` method so you do not need `start_urls`, you can only have either of them

```
import json

class TinyhouselistingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tinyhouselistings'
    listings_url = 'https://thl-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/api/v1/listings/search?area_min=0&measurement_unit=feet&page={}'

    def start_requests(self):
        page = 1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.listings_url.format(page),
            meta={"page": page},
            callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        for ad in resp["listings"]:
            yield ad


        page = int(response.meta['page']) + 1
        if page < int(listings['meta']['pagination']['page_count'])
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.listings_url.format(page),
                meta={"page": page},
                callback=self.parse)
```

From terminal, run spider using to [save scraped data to a JSON file](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data)

```
scrapy crawl tinyhouselistings -o output_file.json
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much Umair! This is so helpful:) The program is now looping through the pages, but the item returned looks to be a string: `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str' in <GET https://thl-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net/api/v1/listings/search?area_min=0&measurement_unit=feet&page=12>` I think the problem is with the ad & listings for loop, and I've tried returning a dict instead of str...any suggestions?

Comment: @Erin see my edited answer, it should ‘listings[“listings”]’